# About conjugation map in second cohomology group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology

I am reading the chapter [Second cohomology groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030402080970146X) of [Continuation of the Notas de Matemàtica](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/north-holland-mathematics-studies/vol/177/suppl/C).

On page 13, the author defines conjugation map.

Let $G$ act on an abelian group $A$ and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Fix $g \in G$ and we choose $\alpha \in Z^2(H,A)$.

Define $c_g(\alpha) \in Z^2(gHg^{-1},A)$ by $c_g(\alpha)(x,y) = {^g \alpha(g^{-1}xg, g^{-1} y g)}$ where $x,y \in gHg^{-1}.$

I have problem in showing that $c_g(\alpha) \in Z^2(gHg^{-1},A). $

I need to verify :$$c_g(\alpha)(x,y)\,\,c_g(\alpha)(xy,z) = {^xc_g(\alpha)(y,z)}\,\, c_g(\alpha)(x,yz). $$
The lhs is $$c_g(\alpha)(x,y) c_g(\alpha)(xy,z) = {^g \alpha(g^{-1}xg, g^{-1}yg)}{^g \alpha(g^{-1}xy g, g^{-1} zg)} = {^g (\alpha(g^{-1}xg, g^{-1}yg) \alpha(g^{-1}xy g, g^{-1} zg) )} .$$

Thus, LHS = $${^g ( {^x \alpha(g^{-1}y g, g^{-1} zg)} \alpha(g^{-1} xg,  g^{-1} yz g))} = {^{gx} \alpha(g^{-1} yg, g^{-1}zg)} ^g\alpha(g^{-1}xg, g^{-1}yzg). $$

But the RHS is $${^xc_g(\alpha)(y,z)}\,\, c_g(\alpha)(x,yz) = {^{xg} \alpha(g^{-1} yg, g^{-1}zg)} ^g \alpha(g^{-1}xg, g^{-1}yzg).$$

Here, I am not getting how ${^{xg} \alpha(g^{-1} yg, g^{-1}zg)} ={^{gx} \alpha(g^{-1} yg, g^{-1}zg)} $?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez It is not clear to me what you are trying to convey. Isn't the action of $H$ on $A$ is the restriction of action of $G$ on $A$?

Comment: [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10yOe53VobvJA9QS4ngPfX2EymElfoJ-x/view?usp=drivesdk) is a screenshot of a page in the book.

Comment: It would be very nice if the downvoter (or someone else) explained their downvote so that I could improve.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a $G$-módule, let $a:H\times H\to A$ be a $2$-cocycle on $G$, and let $g$ be an element of $G$. We define $\bar a:gHg^{-1}\times gHg^{-1}\to A$ putting $$\bar a(x,y)=a(g^{-1}xg,g^{-1}yg)$$ for all choices of $x$ and $y$ in $gHg^{-1}$.

If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are in $gHg^{-1}$, then
\begin{align}
d\bar a(x,y,z)
&=x\cdot\bar a(y,z)-\bar a(xy,z)+\bar a(x,yz)-\bar a(x,y) \\
&=xg\cdot a(g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg)-a(g^{-1}xyg,g^{-1}zg)+a(g^{-1}xg,g^{-1}yxg)-a(g^{-1}xg,g^{-1}yg) \\
&=xg\cdot a(g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg)-g^{-1}xg\cdot a(g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg) +da(g^{-1}xg,g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg) \\
&=xg\cdot a(g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg)-g^{-1}xg\cdot a(g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg) \\
\end{align}
This tells us that $\bar a$ is a $2$-cocycle exactly when $$xg\cdot a(g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg)=g^{-1}xg\cdot a(g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg)$$
for all $x,y,z\in gHg^{-1}$ or, equivalently, when
$$gx\cdot a(y,z)=x\cdot a(y,z)$$
for all $x,y,z\in H$. In particular, if this holds we see that the cocycle $a$ takes values that are fixed by the action of $g$.

Certainly this is not the case in general, so what you want to do is simply impossible.

---

What one *can* do is to define a new $G$-module $B$: as an abelian group, it coincides with $A$, but on $B$ the elements $G$ act differently: if $b$ is an element of $B$ and $k$ one of $G$, we let $$k\triangleright b=gkg^{-1}\cdot b.$$ Here $\cdot$ is the action of $G$ on $A$, and $\triangleright$ is the action of $G$ on $B$. Now we define a map
$\bar a:gHg^{-1}\times gHg^{-1}\to B$ as before, but with values in $B$: we put $$\bar a(x,y)=a(g^{-1}xg,g^{-1}yg)$$ for all choices of $x$ and $y$ in $gHg^{-1}$. I claim that $\bar a$ is a $2$-cocycle on $gHg^{-1}$: if $x,y,z$ are in $gHg^{-1}$, then
\begin{align}
d\bar a(x,y,z)
&=x\triangleright\bar a(y,z)-\bar a(xy,z)+\bar a(x,yz)-\bar a(x,y) \\
&=gxg^{-1}\cdot a(g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg)-a(g^{-1}xyg,g^{-1}zg)+a(g^{-1}xg,g^{-1}yxg)-a(g^{-1}xg,g^{-1}yg) \\
&=da(g^{-1}xg,g^{-1}yg,g^{-1}zg) \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
Voilà.

This $G$-module $B$ is obtained from $A$ by «twisting» the action by $g$.